# How to see the mangrove on Kohama island

Tags: japan, nature-and-wildlife, islands, water-sports, okinawa

The tiny [Kohama island](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Kohama#Get_in) in the very South of Japan has a mangrove ([map](https://tools.wmflabs.org/wikishootme/index.html#lat=24.33890408723922&lng=123.96468400955202&zoom=15)):

[image: Kohama mangrove]

Having never wandered in such an area, I would like to go see it closely.

**QUESTION:** How to get close to it?

Taking the ferry from [Ishigaki](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Ishigaki) to Kohama then walking sounds like the easiest, but I am not sure one can "see" a mangrove on foot. The best would probably be kayaking/canoeing, I guess, but I haven't found any rental place.

Alternatively, are there more accessible mangroves accessible as a day trip from Ishigaki city?

*Picture: https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/File:Mangrove_of_Rhizophoraceaes.jpg*

Answer (score 6):

The [Haimurubushi Hotel](http://www.haimurubushi.co.jp/language/english/activities/index.html) on the island offers:

- **Kayak rental**. Based on my rough estimate from Google maps, the mangrove is about 7km/4mi away.  That would be an easy round trip for an experienced kayaker, I think, but it may be a bit far if you are a novice. (Caveat: IANAK - I am not a kayaker, so *please make sure you get more experienced advice before attempting something like this!*) I don't know whether it would be possible to rent a kayak and transport it somewhere else.
- **A nature tour that includes seeing the mangrove.**

I suspect there may be other options, as well, but perhaps not easily findable in English.  There is a town in the southwest corner of the island, which has a hotel and other tourist amenities.  I would not be at all surprised if it were possible to rent a kayak or other watercraft there.  This would be much closer to the mangrove--perhaps 2km/1.5mi.

**Update:** there are also packaged day tours of Kohama Island that leave from Ishigaki.  Perhaps you can find one of these that includes touring the mangrove.

Comment: OK perfect then. :)